# Oracle: do Truncates maintain Atomicity within a transaction?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, transactions, oracle10g

Oracle 10g -- due to a compatibility issue with a 9i database, I'm pulling data through a 10g database (to be used by an 11g database) using INSERT INTO...SELECT statements via a scheduled job that runs every 15 minutes. I notice that TRUNCATE statements are much faster than DELETE statements and have read that a 'downside' to DELETE statements is that they never decrease the table high-water mark. My use for this data is purely read-only -- UPDATEs and INSERTs are never issued against the tables in question.

Given the above, I want to avoid the possible situation where my 'working' database (Oracle 11g) attempts to read from a table on my staging database (10g) that is empty for a period of time because the TRUNCATE happened straight away and the INSERT INTO...SELECT from the 9i database is taking a couple of minutes to complete.

So, I'm wondering if that is how Oracle handles TRUNCATEs within a transaction, or if the whole operation is performed and COMMITted, despite the fact that TRUNCATEs can't be rolled back? Or, put another way, from an external SELECT point of view, if I wrap a TRUNCANTE and INSERT INTO...SELECT on a table in a transaction, will the table ever appear empty to an external SELECT reading from the table?

Comment: The `TRUNCATE` statement causes an implicit commit. So, immediately  following the `TRUNCATE`, other sessions that start transactions that query the table will see it empty, until rows are added to the table with `INSERT` and `COMMIT`.

Comment: No they don't. Truncate is DDL statement and DDLs always commit. Truncate simply drops the whole table's segment and creates a new one. This operation also invalidates all execution plans against this table in library cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a table has been truncated in a transaction, you cannot do anything else with that table in the same transaction; you have to commit (or rollback) the transaction before you can use that table again.  Or, it may be that truncating a table effectively terminates the current transaction.  Either way, if you use TRUNCATE, you have a window when the table is truncated (empty) but the INSERT operation has not completed.  This is not what you wanted, but it is what Oracle provides.

Comment: I'm wondering how to be a good 'customer' of the middle database (the 10g database). From your answer above, I can't use TRUNCATEs in the per-15-minute job, because I can't have the table empty for unknown periods of time (or at all). But would there be some overall advantage to the 'health' of the middle database if I had a job that ran once a day at midnight, when it's unlikely anyone will be using the end application, to do a TRUNCATE + INSERT INTO...SELECT on the tables? Would that effectively at least reset the table highwater mark once a day? Would there be any other benefit?

Comment: Can you do a three-table shuffle?  Create a table to be loaded, New_TableA, and then load it.  You can then do a shuffle, renaming current TableA to Old_TableA and New_TableA to TableA.  You can then drop Old_TableA.  At the least, this minimizes the time when there isn't a fully populated TableA to the time between two rename operations (which I assume Oracle has). --This could present problems if there are primary or foreign keys on the table, etc; you may have to do some fancy footwork to keep things correct. If this is only used for transferring data between systems, you're probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can do partition exchange. Have 2 partitions in staging table; p_OLD and p_NEW.

1. Before insert do partition exchange "new"->"old" and truncate "new" partition. (At this point if you select from table you see old data)
2. Insert data into "new" partition, truncate "old" partition. (At this point you see new data).

With this approach your table is never empty to the onlooker.

*Why do you need 3 Oracle environments?*